# Swift Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T10, CGFloat)'

Tags: swift, cgfloat

I am a beginner in Swift.

I have this error

Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T10, CGFloat)'

```
func loadBackground(key: NSString, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat) -> UIImage!{


var imageName = key  + "_" + width + "_" + height

return UIImage(named: imageName)!

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error states that you're trying to concat a string and a float (or different types anyway, that cannot be concatenated via `+`). You could just interpolate & construct the string like this instead:

```
func loadBackground(key: NSString, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat) -> UIImage!{

    var imageName = "\(key)_\(width)_\(height)"

    return UIImage(named: imageName)!
}
```

You can read [more about this here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

OK a few more words after @Grimxn's comment...

First of all, specifying `width` and `height` as `CGFloat`s might be handy when calling the method and grabbing values from frame/bounds, but it will most probably bite you in the future (think for example a frame with an almost 'perfect' width like `120.001` - or any crazy number that came out from a division for example). So, I believe that `Int`s would serve better in this case in order to maintain a (relatively safer) mapping between sizes/filenames.

PS. Also a `let` might be preferable over a `var` in your case since `imageName` is just constructed and returned without further modification and finally a `UIImage?` as a return type would force you to handle (or at least check first for) any cases that the image could not be found and hence make your code safer.

Comment: Good answer, but I would ask if OP really means them to be CGFloats - I doubt it, but if he does, we need to know the precision he wants to use as we have no control in interpolation. If not, as is most likely, it's plain wrong for him to be passing CGFloats where he really means Ints. It's that kind of sloppy thinking that Swift is trying to put behind us...

Comment: @Grimxn I totally agree with you. I am trying to be careful with my responses and only focus on the problem rather than on general recommendations about code quality (and making assumptions that could be out of scope of course). Having said that, I m going to edit the answer since it bothers me too. Thanks for the feedback :)